# Prove that if $\hat H | a_n\rangle=a_n|a_n\rangle$, then $f(\hat H)| a_n\rangle=f(a_n)|a_n\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

In Quantum Mechanics you have the eigenvalue equation:

$$\hat H | a_n\rangle=a_n|a_n\rangle \tag{1}$$

where $\hat H$ is the Hamiltonian operator, $\{|a_n\rangle\}$ is a complete set of eigenstates in Hilbert space and $\{a_n\}$ is the set of the eigenvalues (suppose there is no degeneration). So, how would you show that if $f(x):\Re \to  \Re$ (with certain properties to specify later), then follows

$$f(\hat H)| a_n\rangle=f(a_n)|a_n\rangle \tag{2}$$

Some books have this as part of the definition of the function of an operator: $f(\hat H)$, but can you derive (2) from (1) using whatever you need (spectral theory, calculus or whatever)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions of an operator are (or, can be) defined by their power series:
$$f(\hat{A}) = f_0 + f_1 \hat{A} + f_2 \hat{A}^2 + \cdots$$
It's easy to prove that
$$\hat{H}\lvert a_n\rangle = a_n\lvert a_n\rangle
\quad\implies\quad
\hat{H}^k\lvert a_n\rangle = a_n^k\lvert a_n\rangle$$
and if you plug that into the power series definition of the function, it will show that $f(\hat{H})\lvert a_n\rangle = f(a_n)\lvert a_n\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
H\lvert a_n\rangle &= a_n\lvert a_n\rangle \\
H^k\lvert a_n\rangle &= a_n^k\lvert a_n\rangle \\
f(H) &= f(0) + f'(0)H + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}H^2 + \cdots \\
f(H)\lvert a_n\rangle &= \biggl(f(0) + f'(0)a_n + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}a_n^2 + \cdots\biggr)\lvert a_n\rangle = f(a_n)\lvert a_n\rangle
\end{align}$$

We need to assume f can be Taylor expanded.

First calculate the power of $H$, $H$ can commute with itself, so that the eigenvalue is just the power of $a$.